# https Request for CSS file gives 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: asp.net, css, ssl, iis-7, https

recently, I had to add some of my website pages to secure pages by installing SSL. My problem arises when I make a call to a secured web page https://www.myDomain.com/test/httpstest.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://www.myDomain.com/test/Style/Secure/en/BodyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Test Https
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

at this point when calling the page the CSS gives the below response

[image: https request error for CSS file]

noting that the SSL Settings on the Test folder is set to Accept in the IIS 7
[image]

how can I fix this and get the CSS file called over https normally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling your css by just

```
<link href="./test/Style/Secure/en/BodyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When you are using https, it binds it to your whole entire domain name.
If want your css3 to be hidden from the rest the public, this is impossible when you are importing through html. Browsers need this file to render ur html designs properly.